# Can not connect to AWS from public wifi?

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, firewall

I am really confused and I need help.

I was working on my app at a tim horton(Canadian cafe shop) today and I found a bizarre issue where I can't connect(curl or ping) to my AWS ec2 instance or elb, and if I try to ssh I get 
`No route to host`

At first, I thought it was my server, but I can connect to it no problem if I use my phone data.

I was wondering has anybody seen this behavior before? I was thinking could it be that the public cafe wifi has some sort of firewall that blocks specific traffic?

I am using ubuntu and my elb and ec is using http.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I also think that you are using a public wifi where the usage is restricted. It could be a firewall. I have seen this before on airport wifis.

Answer (score 1):

The WiFi Probably blocks SSH port 22? Try using a VPN or see if you can configure AWS to use a different port by logging into the web console

Comment: Maybe it blocks `ssh` connections in general(not just the port)